# Oracle - Erro ao retornar "Nome" + count() - "not a GROUP BY expression"

Tags: oracle

Olá! Estou tentando retornar **os nomes das pessoas** e **a quantidade de carros que cada uma tem** de acordo com as 2 tabelas abaixo, porém acusa o seguinte erro:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
>   00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Aqui minhas 2 tabelas:

```
create table pessoa(
idpessoa number not null,
nome varchar2(40) not null,
constraint pk_idpessoa primary key(idpessoa)
);

create table carro(
idcarro number not null,
nome_carro varchar2(40) not null,
idpessoa number not null,
constraint fk_idcarro foreign key(idpessoa) references pessoaA(idpessoa)
);

/*INSERT'S CASO VOCÊ QUEIRA TESTAR*/
insert into pessoa values(1, 'Maria');
insert into pessoa values(2, 'Joao');

insert into carro values(1, 'Fusca', 1);
insert into carro values(2, 'Kombi', 1);
insert into carro values(3, 'Opala', 2);
```

Retornar somente a quantidade funciona...

```
select count(carro.idcarro) from carro group by carro.idpessoa;
```

Porém, quando coloco para retornar também o nome da pessoa resulta em erro

```
select pessoa.nome, count(carro.idcarro) from pessoa, carro group by carro.idpessoa;
```

Testei essa última linha desse jeito porque no MySQL funciona, já no Oracle não :/.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: select pessoa.nome, count(carro.idcarro) from pessoa, carro group by pessoa.nome; .... no Oracle os campos do select devem estar no "group by"

Comment: Muito obrigado! Não sabia disso! Apesar do código ainda não está gerando o que espero (não mostra de cada pessoa e sim o total), isso me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 1):

Felizmente com comentário do Motta consegui resolver meu problema colocando o campo do SELECT no GROUP BY e adicionando um WHERE:

```
select pessoa.nome, count(carro.idcarro) from pessoa, carro
      where pessoa.idpessoa=carro.idpessoa
      group by carro.idpessoa, pessoa.nome
      order by carro.idpessoa;
```